# Splitting a Graphlab SFrame Date column into three columns (Year Month Day)

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe, graphlab

Given a `graphlab` `SFrame` where there's a column with dates, e.g.:

```
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
| Store |    Date    |  Sales  | Customers |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
|   1   | 2015-07-31 |  5263.0 |   555.0   |
|   2   | 2015-07-31 |  6064.0 |   625.0   |
|   3   | 2015-07-31 |  8314.0 |   821.0   |
|   4   | 2015-07-31 | 13995.0 |   1498.0  |
|   3   | 2015-07-20 |  4822.0 |   559.0   |
|   2   | 2015-07-10 |  5651.0 |   589.0   |
|   4   | 2015-07-11 | 15344.0 |   1414.0  |
|   5   | 2015-07-23 |  8492.0 |   833.0   |
|   2   | 2015-07-19 |  8565.0 |   687.0   |
|   10  | 2015-07-09 |  7185.0 |   681.0   |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
[986159 rows x 4 columns]
```

**Is there an easy way in graphlab / other python function to convert the Date column to Year|Month|Day?**

```
+-------+------+----+----+---------+-----------+
| Store | YYYY | MM | DD |  Sales  | Customers |
+-------+------+----+----+---------+-----------+
|   1   | 2015 | 07 | 31 |  5263.0 |   555.0   |
|   2   | 2015 | 07 | 31 |  6064.0 |   625.0   |
|   3   | 2015 | 07 | 31 |  8314.0 |   821.0   |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
[986159 rows x 4 columns]
```

In `pandas`, I can do this: [Which is the fastest way to extract day, month and year from a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954197/which-is-the-fastest-way-to-extract-day-month-and-year-from-a-given-date)

But to convert an SFrame into Panda to split date and convert back into SFrame is quite a chore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do it with the split-datetime method. It gives you a bit more flexibility.

```
sf.add_columns(sf['Date'].split_datetime(column_name_prefix = ''))
```

The `split_datetime` method itself is on the `SArray` (a single column of the SFrame) and it returns an SFrame which you can then add back to the original data (at basically 0 cost)

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way to do this is

```
sf['date2'] = sf['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-'))
sf = sf.unpack('date2')
```

Another option would be to convert the `Date` column to a datetime type, then use the `graphlab.SArray.split_datetime` function.